# Filter array in javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an array which including all of the times as below :

```
["14:00-14:30" , "14:30-15:00", "15:00-15:30"]
```

as you can see this time slots, so basically, its from : 14:00 to 15:30

output will be : `["14:00-15:30"]`

But if i have :

```
["14:00-14:30", "14:30-15:00", "15:30-16:00"]
```

in this case, the output would be : `["14:00-15:00", "15:30-16:00"]`

My solution: convert all of this to a single array `["14:00", "14:30", "14:30", "15:00", ...]`. And then forEach to each element, delete the one the have `arr[i] === arr[i+1].`

I got it working but I don't really like the way its. is there any better idea or how to use filter in this case ? Thanks.

Comment: those arrays are not valid. I would assume they are strings, is it correct?

Comment: Yes you are correct. those are string. let me edit my question. my bad

Comment: Notice that `arr[i] === arr[i+1]` only won't work since you will just are doing `uniq` and not removing both instances of the dups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the format of the array is correct:

```
const yourArray = ["14:00-14:30", "14:30-15:00", "15:30-16:00"];
const solution = yourArray.sort().reduce(
    (acc, item, index) => {
        if (index===0) {
            acc.push(item);
            return acc;
        }
        const currentValueParsed = acc[acc.length-1].split('-');
        const newValueParsed = item.split('-');
        if (currentValueParsed[1] === newValueParsed[0]) {
            acc[acc.length-1] = `${currentValueParsed[0]}-${newValueParsed[1]}`;
            return acc;
        }
        acc.push(item);
        return acc;
    }, []
);
console.log(solution); // ["14:00-15:00", "15:30-16:00"]
```

The code could be small, but I prefer being explicit.

- We sort the array.
- We add the first element to the final array.
- And every new element, ee decide if we need to modify the last element of the solution array or add the new element to this array.

And because you look interested in evolve your original solution.

```
const yourArray = ["14:00-14:30", "14:30-15:00", "15:30-16:00"];
const solution = yourArray.sort()
    .join('-')
    .split('-')
    .filter((item, pos, arr) => {
        return pos === 0 || (item !== arr[pos - 1] && item !== arr[pos + 1]);
    })
    .reduce((acc, item, pos, arr) => {
        if (pos % 2) {
            acc.push(`${arr[pos - 1]}-${arr[pos]}`);
        }
        return acc;
    }, []);
console.log(solution); // ["14:00-15:00", "15:30-16:00"]
```

Notes:

- It is important to sort in the beginning.
- `pos % 2` is telling me if it is an even position.
- I don't care `arr[pos + 1]` return undefined in the last item.

Comment: what do u think if i just convert all of this to array and remove all the duplicated. [14:00, 14:30,14:30: 15:00] => [14:00, 15:00]

Comment: It is a good idea. I propose just another way as you ask. Just that you have to reconstruct the array at the end.

Comment: @daniel8x I update the answer with the possibility you propose. I still thinking the first one is cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

Filter won't work, since you're creating a new value, not just keeping existing values. Reduce would, though.

```
let start = null, end = null;
let finalAnswer = arr.reduce((result, current, i) => {
  const [first, last] = current.split('-');
  if (start === null) { start = first;}
  if (first !== end && end !== null) { result.push(`${start}-${end}`); if (i === arr.length - 1) { result.push(current); }}
  else if (i === arr.length - 1) { result.push(`${start}-${last}`); }
  else { end = last; }
  return result;
}, []);
```

I'm sure there's a cleaner way to do this -- I had to throw in edge cases more than I'd like -- but this works :)

The idea is that you keep track of the interval's start and end times; if the current interval's start equals the last interval's end, then update the end time to the current interval's. Otherwise, push the current start and end time and reset the counter for the next entry. The edge cases are to handle when the final entry either does or does not create its own new interval; if it does, push the entry as its own interval, and if not, push a new interval with the current start and the entry's end time.

Answer (score 1):

this is really a reduce operation, so a solution could like:

```
const result = array
                 .sort() // if needed?
                 .map(tf => tf.split('-')) // make it easier to work with
                 .reduce((acc, currFrame, idx, arr) => {
                   let reducedFrame = acc[acc.length - 1] // get latest reduced frame
                   if (!reducedFrame || reducedFrame.length === 2) { // filled range or at start
                     reducedFrame = [currFrame[0]] // so start a new one
                     acc.push(reducedFrame)
                   }
                   const nextFrame = arr[idx + 1]
                   if (!nextFrame || nextFrame[0] !== currFrame[1]) { // at last frame or end of the current continuous frame
                     reducedFrame.push(currFrame[1]) // so end the reduced frame
                   }
                   return acc
                 }, [])
                 .map(tf => tf.join('-')) // put it back
```

or the dupe filter approach would work as well I believe, building off @Dalorzo:

```
const result = array
                 .join('-').split('-') // convert to array of singles
                 .filter((v,i) => array.indexOf(v) === i) // lose the dupes
                 .sort() // if needed (performs better here in this case)
                 .reduce((acc, cur, i, arr) =>  // join every 2
                   (i % 2 === 0)
                     ? acc.concat([cur + '-' + arr[i + 1]])
                     : acc, [])
```

Comment: what do u think if i just convert all of this to array and remove all the duplicated. [14:00, 14:30,14:30: 15:00] => [14:00, 15:00]

Comment: sounds like it'd work, but you'd have to split / reduce, dup filter, then join / reduce every 2 items to put it back together, I'm just not sure it's simpler / more performant

Comment: That what i am going to test it out. Thanks

Comment: let me know, a dup filter is operationally complex.  I think big O on first method is ~4n and on dupe method might be ~3n + n^2, but probably doesn't matter if your lists are small anyway

Answer (score 0):

In order to create the desired array what I would do is to `join` and `split` like:

```
var arr =['14:00-14:30', '14:30-15:00', '15:30-16:00'];
var arr = arr.join('-').split('-');
```

The above will produce the array with all times and then you could remove the duplicates any way you want one way:

```
 var result = arr.filter((v,i) => arr.indexOf(v) === i);
```

Comment: he's reducing all the continuous frames

Comment: I don't think it is about continuous but duplicates

Comment: this `["14:00-14:30", "14:30-15:00", "15:30-16:00"]` goes to `["14:00-15:00", "15:30-16:00"]`.. could be misinterpreting but it seems to be a reduction to continuous time frames

Comment: @Dalorzo Your answer is the same idea with what i am thinking right now. Let me try to add some more test case to see if it passes.

Comment: just need to reduce at the end to join every 2 items and you're done if you want this approach